# ReactJS and React native component Library for styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm in the process of learning React JS and I wanted to use one of these library for my styling

- ReactStrap
- Material UI

The next step for me is to learn React Native as well , and I'm wondering if there will be a similar styling library for both react js and react native with very few differences?

So I could learn and use one library for both react js and react native rather than using two different things for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, I'm using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) for my reactjs app and [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui/) for my react-native app. The two libraries are similar (not equal) but very similar and once you learned how to use one, the other one is quite simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I`m using [Themeor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/themeor) for both: React and React Native. This library has a similar approach to build styled components for React and React Native.

You don`t need to use Stylesheet in React Native and .css files in React projects. You better should read this [article](https://opium-pro.medium.com/standardisation-of-color-schemes-through-the-eyes-of-a-programmer-53cc25148470) about Themeor component and colors using.